# F# Не обнаруживается функция: "The value or constructor 'test' is not defined"

Tags: функции, f#

Вот весь код

```
#indent "off"

let test b c =
    b + c

test 1 2
```

В последней строке подчеркнуто слово "test" и написано "The value or constructor 'test' is not defined".
Работаю в Visual Studio, консольное приложение

Comment: Насколько понимаю вы только начинаете свое знакомство с F#. Первые шаги всегда самые сложные, а поддержка более опытных разработчиков является залогом быстрого и успешного старта. Сообщество F# пока хоть и не большое, но очень дружелюбное, поэтому предлагаю присоединиться к [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) где вы самостоятельно сможете это проверить. Там даже есть специальный канал для общения на русском языке. Если возникнут какие-либо вопросы об F# или сообществе вы также можете спросить в [F# комната](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) на SO на русском.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался сам.
Сначало нужно было с помощью Alt-Enter "оценить" функцию "test", а уже затем Alt-Enter-ить последнюю строку.

Comment: Если правильно понял, в вопросе и ответе идет речь об `fsi`?